# Thoughts on loading images in android app

Tags: java, android, memory-management, drawable

I'm working on an android game, and the concept is quite sound, but i'm constantly frustrated by outofmemory errors and finding myself spending the majority of my time attempting to avoid them.

As of now, all animation is done in a canvas using png image resources. I'm guessing that some of the bigger apps don't quite use this method since much more graphically impressive games than mine exist and run much better.

Where i'm getting the problems is when I first load the image resources and assign them to variable handles. I load all the images from the very beginning of the app starting in a constructor, and I often hit the outofmemory error at this point usually on devices running android 2.1 more so.

So my question is how can I avoid this or change the way i'm doing the animation to be easier on memory.

Re-scaling helps temporarily, but is unacceptable as a long term solution, I want the images to look good. And like I said, other apps look good and have much more animation so i'm sure it's possible to do this.

The other option I've been suggested is to more closely control the object lifecycles to only allocate images when I need them. This doesn't seem to be an ideal solution either because do to the setup of my app, most of the images need to be drawn most of the time, or at least may be called at any time.

My last idea is to possibly add in some code that de-allocates the memory when an image is not immediately being used. Again this doesn't seem ideal because in circumstances when for instance there is a single enemy on the canvas, every time his frame changes he would need to re-allocate an image for it, killing performance.

Anyone have any general ideas I should look into? I know i'm missing something big. Can I manually make the available memory larger? Is there a format of image with a smaller memory footprint.

I'm trying to get a better knowledge of the basics of whats at work here.
My entire drawable folder is only 864kb, That seems ridiculous to me. What is happening that makes 864kb worth of images exceed the memory limits? I'd like to know specifically where the problem is occurring. I need a solution, not a workaround.

Edit: I've also noticed that OpenGL seems to be the alternative to canvas I've been using. I've never used OpenGL... is this what i'm looking for? and if yes, how difficult would it be to switch from simply drawing to canvas to the equivalent in OpenGL?